# NATIVE_APP context are showing on a hybrid Android app which is using Cordova , when trying to automate using Appium

Tags: android, python, automation, appium

```
    def test_list_content(self):
      self.driver.implicitly_wait(600)
      time.sleep(10)
      allContexts = self.driver.contexts
      print allContexts
      current = self.driver.current_context
      print current
```

Appium version is 1.4.16.1, Windows 7, Android device with OS 4.4.2.

I'm working with an hybrid app and the Appium only returns the NATIVE_APP context. I can see the app in chrome inspector and able to click on web elements using that but using Appium I am not able to switch to Web view because of which appium is not able to find the elements on screen.

Please help how can I automate this kind of Android App

Comment: Question! Are you using Crosswalk in the hybrid app? Usually this causes issues with the webview not being found.

Comment: @MadisKangro, yes crosswalk is present in our app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Crosswalk webviews. They are a little different. This hasn't been fixed in the appium yet. Issue is here
[Appium issue with Crosswalk webviews.](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4597)

But there is a workaround for the issue here. Follow the instructions there and it should work then. I did try it out and it worked for me. The webview name was a little bit different that usual. 
 [Crosswalk workaround for appium](https://github.com/ITKarel/ChromeDriver)